# Mysql query left join access to variable

Tags: mysql, join, repeat

If someone can help me with this one I've got these tables And I would like to get all bookings between two dates, and to know whether any of it is done by someone else or it is fail.

Table:Bookings

```
id | date     |  date_end   | repeat | day_of_week | user_id | price
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2013-07-01   0000-00-00   1        3             1         20
2   2013-07-16   0000-00-00   1       -1             1         10
```

Table:Bookings_done_by_other

```
id | date     | user_id   | booking_id
---------------------------------
1   2013-07-01  2           2
2   2013-07-13  2           2
```

Table:Bookings_fail

```
id | date     | booking_id
---------------------------
1   2013-07-01  2
2   2013-07-11  2
```

Table:Tally

```
id
--
1
....
500
```

Here is my query which is working well, but I can't manage with it to give me all what I want.

```
SELECT f.date as fail, b.id, b.date, a.showdate, DATEDIFF(b.date, a.showdate) AS diff
FROM  bookings as b
LEFT JOIN bookings_fail f ON (b.id = f.booking_id and DATE(f.date) = DATE(a.showdate) )
,
(
SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-07-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL Id DAY) as showdate
FROM `tally` 
WHERE (DATE_ADD('2013-07-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL Id DAY) <= '2013-07-20 00:00:00')
ORDER BY Id ASC
)  a 
WHERE 
MOD(DATEDIFF(b.date, a.showdate), b.repeat) = 0
AND 
DATE(a.showdate)>= DATE(b.date)
```

when is like this is throw error that cant see a.showdate in left join, when I move the left join next to "a" table is throw error that cant see b.id so **Is there any way to get this join working?**

I would like to get result something like this

```
id | showdate | fail | by_other | 
-----------------------------
1   2013-07-01  NULL    2
2   2013-07-01  1       NULL     //Or date
1   2013-07-03  NULL    NULL
1   2013-07-04  NULL    NULL
1   2013-07-05  NULL    NULL
1   2013-07-06  NULL    NULL
.............................
1   2013-07-20  NULL    NULL
```

Sorry if My English is not too good, and Thanks in advance to everyone who can help.

Here some pictures hope is getting clear I cant explain what I want properly

This is bookings
[Booking table](http://s9.postimg.org/bc7tu4e67/image.jpg)

This is fail

[Fail table](http://s17.postimg.org/bs03jup4f/image.jpg)

I cant put more than 2 links so that's why these two are just like text
so what's happening when I want to get my bookings for some date I do this

s16.postimg.org/l00k1math/image.jpg

What I want to have done is

s12.postimg.org/5o5hbnmdp/image.jpg

But not only for booking with id 1 I wont to be b.id = un.booking_id and then if there is record for fail to appear how is on the last picture

Thanks for your patience

Comment: The data you have provided doesn't seem to make sense. The records in the *fail* and *other* tables all have the same booking_id (i.e. 2), but none of their dates match up with the date for booking number 2 in the booking table. Is that correct? What is the 1 in the fail column of the output supposed to mean? What is the 2 in the by_other column supposed to mean? What purpose does the repeat column serve?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain well the dates are important only in bookings table, they will appear in this loop which is done by tally table, so when some booking is in between the given dates or is in period will appear in this statement, and here I want to put left join to add if on some of the dates generated by tally "showdate" has fail or the booking is done by another user so later I can show in my calendar. If I put this check in my where clause it is brake the loop which I need because my bookings should repeat. I hope this make any sance

Comment: I still don't understand. In the second result line (`2  2013-07-01  1  NULL`), where does the id 2 come from? Is that meant to be the booking id? The booking on that date has an id of 1, not 2, so that doesn't make sense to me. And why is it a fail? Because the date matches a fail date? If so, why doesn't the first result line show a fail since it has the same show date? And why do the first two results have the same show date anyway? You have two of `2013-07-01` but no `2013-07-02`.

Comment: @James Holderness Hi I put some pictures of my active tables and queries sorry about my last explanations I have to study more English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understand what you are trying to do. My suggestion is to format your query like this:

```
SELECT b.id, a.showdate, f.id as fail, o.id as other
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-07-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL Id DAY) as showdate
  FROM `tally` 
  WHERE (DATE_ADD('2013-07-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL Id DAY) <= '2013-07-20 00:00:00')
  ORDER BY Id ASC
) a
LEFT JOIN Bookings b ON (
  MOD(DATEDIFF(b.date, a.showdate), b.repeat) = 0 AND 
  DATE(a.showdate)>= DATE(b.date)             
)
LEFT JOIN Bookings_fail f ON (
  b.id = f.booking_id AND 
  DATE(f.date) = DATE(a.showdate) 
)
LEFT JOIN Bookings_done_by_other o ON (
  b.id = o.booking_id AND 
  DATE(o.date) = DATE(a.showdate)
)
```

You start by selecting from the generated *a* table, and join that with the *Bookings* table. Once you have those two joined it's easy to join any other tables based on the `a.showdate` and the `b.id` fields.

I've created a SQL Fiddle example, more or less based on your data, so you can see how it works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e151/1

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I wanted